# Why are my Adaptive Trigger not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When I first run the code it work fine 
After a several debug and it just can't active the trigger[image]

I dont know why

But in the design screen it show up the layout I wanted

[image]

Here is the XAML code

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveLayout">
            <VisualState x:Name="PhoneDisplay">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="RelativePanelTop.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="RadialProgressBarControl1.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="StackMember.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="UploadSpeedText.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="ToolsGrid.Width" Value="*"/>
                    <Setter Target="RightPB.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="TabletDisplay">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1500"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="RelativePanelTop.Visibility" Value="Visibile"/>
                    <Setter Target="RadialProgressBarControl1.Visibility" Value="Visibile"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Unable to test your code right now, but as you said these codes working properly before, so can you close vs and empty your obj and bin folder or clean solution and reopen vs and build solution again

Comment: I've just deteled them

Comment: but nothing working

Answer (score 3):

When Adaptive Triggers don't work, the first thing I check is if I haven't made a spelling error in the names of the controls somewhere. The easiest thing to do is to comment out all setters and then uncomment them one by one to see if they work gradually. The problem is that when any setter's `Target` or `Value` is misspelled, the whole trigger will seize to work completely, although it will not throw any exception.

My guess is that the problem will be with

```
<Setter Target="RelativePanelTop.Visibility" Value="Visibile"/>
<Setter Target="RadialProgressBarControl1.Visibility" Value="Visibile"/>
```

It seems you accidentally spelled `"Visibile"` instead of `"Visible"`.

Comment: Thanks for the detail but the code I need is in MinimumWidth 1500. It "0" Even the design view show it as you can see in my picture

Comment: I understand, but as I said - even a small typo will break all states even if it is just in one of them. Try to verify all names and values are indeed correct

Answer (score 0):

Found it ! 
This property mess all of them up, I dont why but when I delete it everything work

```
<Setter Target="ToolsGrid.Width" Value="*"/>
```

Comment: You want `Value="Auto"` for that, not *

Comment: I was also think you can set  auto or fixed value on this. But currently not with my pc.

Comment: Are you setting the width of Grid or a ColumnDefinition? You can use star for ColumnDefinition, but for Grid itself the analogous would be to set HorizontalAlignment to Stretch instead.